# I have json file on local computer i want to use that file in javascript how can i use that in js

Tags: javascript, json

Following is the code snippet which i am trying

```
var json = require('dictonery.json'); //(with path)
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Use JSON.parse(//your json string)

Comment: The require statement is not JavaScript. You seem to mix JS and PHP.

Comment: Does local computer mean it is not stored on the same machine as the code?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user yup my bad i am new to this :P

Comment: @some-non-descript-user yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

You should do

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
```

// this will show the info it in firebug console
});

Comment: This assumes the OP uses Jquery.

Comment: the above code give me following error in console
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/HAMIDKHAN/Desktop/dic/dictionary.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so from your comments I assume you have the following scenario: You have a server somewhere running your code and you have a local machine where the JSON file is stored. That won't work, if the local machine is not running a web server allowing you to load the JSON to the machine running the code. You could do this in that case e.g. by using PHP's `file()` function or via an Ajax call. I'd rather recommend to upload it first, so all files are in the same file system.

If you create the JS from a PHP enabled file you could do the following:

```
var json = '<?php require('dictonery.json') ?>'; //(with path)
console.log(json);
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(jsonObj);
```

The `require` loads the file holding your JSON data (given that it is accessible) and puts it into the js file so that it ends up in a string variable. The `JSON.parse` creates a Javascript object from this string, so that you can actually use the data.